# Is spoiled in a good use here ?

Tags: synonyms, syntactic-analysis

For example I want to know if my actions did "ruin" someones weekend, but use for ruin a softer/nicer word can this be "spoil" and the sentence would look like this:

I hope i did not spoil your weekend too much

Thanks for help and fast answer ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both "ruin" and "spoil" are strong words and whilst your sentence was fine, it really only allows one polite answer. After all, if the recipient came back and said:

"Actually you did spoil my weekend"

.. it indicates that the whole weekend was ruined.

My preference would be a softer alternative:

"I hope I didn't mess your weekend up too much."
or
"I hope I didn't disrupt things too much."

Some people will still be reticent about causing offence, so you could take the initiative and say:

"I know I caused a bit of a problem but I hope it wasn't too awful!"

Comment: thanks allot for your answer, lets see if its going to work ;)